# Conditional Probability on Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ a standard Brownian motion, with $t\geq0$. Determine:

(a)$P(W_2>0|W_1>0)$;

(b)$P(W_2-W_1>0|W_1=0)$.

For point (b) I try to do this:

$P(W_2-W_1>0|W_1=0)=P(W_2-W_1-W_1>0-0|W_1=0)=$*(by indipendent increments)*$=P(W_2-2W_1>0)=P(Z>0)=1-P(Z\leq0)$, where $Z=W_2-2W_1$.

W_1 and W_2 are two Normal variable (for Brownian motion) so also Z is a Normal variable with $\mu$(=mean value)=$1*\mu_2+(-2)*\mu_1=1*0-2*0=0$, where $\mu_i$ is mean value of $W_i$, and $\sigma^2$(=variance)=$(1)^2*\sigma^2_2+(-2)^2*\sigma^2_1=1*t+4*t=5t$, where $\sigma^2_i$ is variance of $W_i$.

So, $1-P(Z\leq0)=1-\int_{-\infty}^{0}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi5t}}\right)e^0dx}=1-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{10\pi t}}\right)$

Is it correct?

For point (a) I don't know how do, so I hope that someone can help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: For part b) you just need to know that the increment is independent of the the initial value, then it will be very easy. Part a) may need more tricks to do as you probably need to express $W_2 = (W_2 - W_1) + W_1$ and exploit the independence. Apply the definition of conditional probability and visualize the joint pdf of a pair of independent bivariate normal.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to use your advices but I didn't manage to solve the part a) anyway.. Can you show me more details? Thanks again